# Create a last url column from current list of hits

Tags: mysql

I currently have the following columns:

```
hit_id, visit_id, timestamp, page_url, page_next
```

`hit_id` increments upwards
`visit_id` is an ID of the visit and unique to each visitor
`timestamp` is a unix timestamp of the hit
`page_url` is the page being looked at
`page_next` is the page that was looked at next

I would like to to add a new column, `page_last`, where the previous page URL would go into - I should be able to extract this from `page_url` and `page_next`. I do not know why I did not create this column in the first place, probably a slight over-site really.

Is there anyway to fill this column using some MySQL trickery? `page_last` would always be empty on the initial hit on the website (doesn't contain referrer website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the name `page_last` ambiguous (does it mean the previous page?  or this last page on the visit?).  I suggest you change it to `page_prev`.

The following comes close to filling this in, assuming that no one visited the same page multiple times in a visit:

```
select h.*, hprev.page_url as page_prev
from hits h left outer join
     hits hprev
     on hprev.page_next = h.page_url and hprev.visit_id = h.visit_id
```

If that is not true, then you need the most recent one.  You can get that using a correlated subquery:

```
select h.*,
       (select h2.page_url
        from hits h2
        where h2.visit_id = h.visit_id and h2.page_next = h.page_url and
              h2.timestamp < h.timestamp
        order by timestamp desc
        limit 1
       ) as page_prev
from hits h
```

Doing the update is a bit tricky in MySQL, because you are not able to directly use the updated table in the update.  But, the following trick should work:

```
update hits
    set page_prev = (select page_url
                     from (select page_url
                           from hits h2
                           where h2.visit_id = hits.visit_id and
                                 h2.page_next = hits.page_url and
                                 h2.timestamp < hits.timestamp
                           order by timestamp desc
                           limit 1
                          ) h3
                    )
```

The trick works because MySQL materializes views, so it actually creates a "temporary table" containing the necessary information for the update.

Comment: Thanks for the above, though is the update part correct? I ask because I see derived table `h` appearing in the query but not declared in the 3rd chunk. Also, the most inner part `h2.visit_id=hits.visit_id` isn't that the exact same table looking at itself? But yes, `url_prev` sounds much better :o)

Comment: @MrJ . . . that should have been `hits`.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I don't know why though, but I keep getting the message `#1054 - Unknown column 'hits.visit_id' in 'where clause'` when that column and table definitely exist - also get told that every derived table must have an alias too, but for that I just gave it the name `hits2`